# Set size and position images in regions of jvectormap

Tags: javascript, html, css, jvectormap

I am building a website in which I am integrating a map created with the JVectorMap library, each region instead of being colored must have a background image which represents the region, all right up to here, the problem is that when inserting the images they are repeated throughout the region without showing all the size, and what I need to do is show as much as possible of the image only once.

**This is my code from JVectorMap:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
        <head>
           <title>IDTravel</title>
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-jvectormap-2.0.3.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
  <script src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery-jvectormap-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery-jvectormap-world-mill.js"></script>
  <style>
     html, body{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;

     }
     pattern img{
      width: 100%;
     }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="world-map" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
  <script>
    $(function(){
      new jvm.Map({
        container: $('#world-map'),
        map: 'world_mill',
        series: {
          regions: [{
            scale: {
              redGreen: 'img.jpg',
              yellowBlue: 'img1.jpg'
            },
            values: {
              "US": 'redGreen',
              "MX": 'yellowBlue'
            },
          }]
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**This is the result:**

[image: The Result]

Comment: Please, add your html and css so we can help you better